# Navigating View to View in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I'd love some input on how how to navigate from view to view within the context of a submitHandler using JQuery Validator. What I'm doing currently is roughly,

```
class Example.ViewOne extends Backbone.View
    template: JST['view_one']

    render: ->
      @$el.html(template())
      @$('form').validate(@.validators)
      this

    validators:
      rules:
        name:
          required: true
      submitHandler: (form) ->
        view = new Example.ViewTwo()
        view.render()
        return false

class Example.ViewTwo extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['view_two']
  
  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template())
    this

class ExampleRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '' : 'index'
  
  index:
    view = new Example.ViewOne()
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

Hosting Page:

```
...
<div id="container"></div>
....
```

ViewOne:

```
  ...
  <h1>View One</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <button type="submit" />
  </form>
  ...
```

ViewTwo:

```
  ...
  <h1>View Two</h1>
  ...
```

What happens is when I hit submit on ViewOne the post triggers and just re-renders ViewOne. I would like to render ViewTwo and not have the post happen. I must work with JQuery Validator and it requires, to my knowledge, a form tag so getting rid of the form tag can't be a solution for me.

Also, I'm aware that controlling workflow within views is not the ideal way, but I'm focused on justing getting something simple to work for now and definitely plan on investigating more robust solutions as I become more comfortable with Backbone.

Comment: Not comfortable with coffeescript nor with jQuery validator but shouldn't your `$el` be `@$el`? Also, it doesn't seem that you're appending your second view's element to the DOM. Other questions: is your submitHandler executed? Have you any real use of jQuery validator?

Comment: Yes you're correct about the missing @. That's doesn't make a difference however.  What do mean by the second view's element isn't getting appended to the DOM?  

The submitHanlder is getting executed and have to use JQuery validator.